# NodeJS Loop not awaiting for .then as well

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

I currently have a loop inside my async function which looks like this:

```
async function getInfo(){

  for(var i=0; i < 550; i++){

      await client.decodeRecaptchaV2({
        googlekey: 'xxx',
        pageurl: 'website.com'
      }).then(async function(response) {

        await enter(i, response);

      });
  }

}
```

My problem is that the loop waits for the **decodeRecaptchaV2** function to finish, and then repeats itself without waiting for the **enter** function in the then statement to finish as well.

I need the loop to run both the **decodeRecaptchaV2** function, THEN the **enter** function, and THE repeat the loop.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: a) I would not use the `.then()` pattern, if `async/await` is available and in particular not mix both of them. b) is `enter()` coded by you or are you sure it is actually supporting the Promise-pattern?

Comment: @Sirko enter() is coded by myself yes. I cannot see another workaround for the .then() pattern since that is utilised by an npm library

Comment: `async/await` is basically just syntactic sugar for using `then()`. So you should be able to use it here. If `enter()` is also by you, can you add the source of that? Most likely the issue is with that function as the currently given code seems fine.

Comment: Does `enter()` return a promise?  If so, you can just do `return enter(i, response)`.  If not, then that's your problem as it needs to for this to work.

Comment: You could show us what exactly `enter` functions does.

Answer (score 2):

```
let req = 550
req.foreach(async element => {

await client.decodeRecaptchaV2({
        googlekey: 'xxx',
        pageurl: 'website.com'
      }).then(async function(response) {

        await enter(element , response);

      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix async patterns. If you want the benefit of `async` and `await`, which automate the process of handling Promise data, then don't also use explicit Promise.then():

```js
async function getInfo() {
  for(let i=0; i < 550; i++){
    const response = await client.decodeRecaptchaV2({
      googlekey: `google-key-value`,
      pageurl: `example.com`
    });

    const e = await enter(i, response);

    // maybe with error generation, because I have no idea what your code does:
    if (!e) {
      throw new Error(`...`);
    }
  }
}
```

Why you would wait for 550 decode attemps in series as part of something called "getInfo", though... no idea, that seems really weird, and hints at a much larger problem; but if you just want to know how to fix the problem as posted, this is it.

Comment: This isn't a solution.  If `enter()` properly returns a promise that is linked to its asynchronous operation, then the OP's code would work as well as this.  So, this doesn't actually solve anything.

Comment: It certainly solves one problem, namely the pattern mixing, and if what you say is true (which it probably is), that's now far easier to debug. Even if it doesn't solve the underlying problem, it certainly solves more than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
you should not write code in node js if this is the case. two await 550 times???
```

use for...of loop if you need to use await inside.

```
{
    var a = await b();
    var c = await d(a);
}
```

what you have written looks like combination of promise ans async await.